# NSURLConnect works only 1 time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to do a request but it works only in the first time....

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *infos = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *thumbPath = thePath;

NSURLRequest *thumbRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbPath]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

self->thumbConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:thumbRequest
                                                        delegate:self
                                                startImmediately:YES];

     self->thumbData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
```

when receive Response

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

if (self->thumbData == nil) {
    self->thumbData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

self.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self->thumbData];

self.thumbActivityView.hidden = YES;

self->thumbData = nil;
}
```

when didFinishDownloading: 
  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

```
self.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self->thumbData];

self.thumbActivityView.hidden = YES;

[self->thumbData release];

self->thumbData = nil;
```

}

when timeout or other erros method:

```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[self->thumbData release];
self->thumbData = nil;
self.thumbActivityView.hidden = YES;
[thumbConnection release];
self->thumbConnection = nil;

}
```

Comment: What happens the 2nd or 3rd time?

Comment: I can see a `release` call there, so it looks like MRR.  However you don't appear to be `release`'ing all the stuff you `alloc`. That is probably the issue.

Comment: And do you need to allocate a new connection each time, or can you re-use the existing one (if there is one)?  I don't know, but I suspect you can re-use the existing one.

Comment: I need to do a new request in Connection

Comment: Don't allocate it again if it's non-`nil`.  Better still allocate it in your object's `init` method and `release` it in your object's `dealloc` method.

Comment: but I set the request in init from NSURLconnection, if I don't alloc again, how can I change the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't allocate it again if it's non-nil. Better still allocate it in your object's init method and release it in your object's dealloc method